# How to set the width and height constraint for the view inside the navigation bar using storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift4

I have added the view inside the navigation bar using the storyboard and set it width and height constraint.
But next time when I am opening the project the width and height constraint of the view get automatically set by the value zero for both width and height.